# Timer control memory consumption

Tags: c#, windows, timer

I'm using timer control to fire a method in every second and in the task manager I can see the memory which allocates to the application is going high rapidly.in the timer tick I'm only assigning a string to a label for the testing purposes.

Code example:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label1.Text == "5")
        label1.Text = "10";
    else
        label1.Text = "5";

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: prove us with code.. this should not costume memory.

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "1";
            label1.Text = "10";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

Comment: I dont know why the code coming like this

Comment: You are trying to change the Text value of a label twice within a second with UI updates that will overlap, do you expect to see either of the values changing?

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label1.Text == "5")
                label1.Text = "10";
            else
                label1.Text = "5";
           
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

Comment: Oki check this code now... I just want to fire a timer tick without getting memory leak ...

Comment: This cannot leak. You are not allocating anything. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This is my whole application.. you also can do the same and have a look of the memory consumption.. its growing rapiedly

Comment: how often does your timer fire - on my side there is no memory leak if I set it to 1sek...

Comment: Its 1 sec in my side also.. I can see the allocated memory is going higher and higher in task manager

Answer (score -1):

got it,Your time_tick make your CPU going high rapidly,once if you input "5",it become 10;and next time,when time_tick fire this mothed,it go to "5",because if this time you input is "10".

Comment: man this is an very poor answer - I will not downvote it for now since your are new here but please change it to make any sense

Comment: You are correct .. can you please explain why the allocated memory size is growing when I set timer interval to 1000 (1sec)